# Why do I get "unused global options warning" for options forwarded to a package except for the first option?

Tags: warnings, package-writing, documentclass-writing, latex-base, bugs

I am working on a custom package for my macros and shortcuts, and a custom class for my preferred style of the document. I am using `DeclareKeys` to define key-value options in my package, and then my class, which loads this package, forwards the options to it globally by forwarding them to the base class (article). It works well, but I get weird warnings about unused global options. Here's the code:

```latex
% demo-pkg.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{demo-pkg}[Demo]

\RequirePackage{xstring}

\DeclareKeys[my]
{
    lang.choices:nn =
        { english, hebrew }
        {\ExpandArgs{Nc}\let\@my@lang{l_keys_choice_tl}},
    lang.usage = load,
    lang.initial:n = english,
    notation.choices:nn =
        { physics, math }
        {\ExpandArgs{Nc}\let\@my@notation{l_keys_choice_tl}},
    notation.usage = load,
    notation.initial:n = physics,
    foo.choices:nn =
        { bar, baz }
        {\ExpandArgs{Nc}\let\@my@foo{l_keys_choice_tl}},
    foo.usage = load,
    foo.initial:n = bar
}

\ProcessKeyOptions[my]

\RequirePackage{xparse}

\IfStrEqCase{\@my@notation}{%
{physics}{%
\NewDocumentCommand{\Conjugate}{ m }{{##1}^{\ast}}%
}%
{math}{%
\NewDocumentCommand{\Conjugate}{ m }{\overline{##1}}%
}%
}%
```

```latex
% demo-cls.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{demo-cls}[Demo class]

\DeclareKeys[demo-cls]
{
    unknown.code = \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}
}

\ProcessKeyOptions[demo-cls]

\LoadClass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\RequirePackage{demo-pkg}
```

```latex
% main.tex
\documentclass[lang=hebrew, notation=math, foo=baz]{demo-cls}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[ z = x + iy \Longleftrightarrow \Conjugate{z} = x - iy \]
\end{document}
```

Running this code produces the correct document, but I get a warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [notation,foo].
```

My package clearly picked up these options and used them (I only show usage of the `notation` option for simplicity), so why do I get this warning, and why is there no warning for the first option `lang=hebrew`?

Changing the order of the options to `\documentclass[notation=math, lang=hebrew, foo=baz]{demo-cls}` changes the warning to

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [lang,foo].
```

The document still compiles and looks fine though.

Why do I get warnings for every option except the first one, and how can I solve these warnings?

Comment: Seems like a strange bug in `\ProcessKeyOptions`, if I recode your package with `expkv-opt` instead I don't get any unknown option warnings.

Comment: Does your real class have any options of its own? If not, consider to use `\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper, 12pt}{article}\LoadClassWithOptions{article}` instead of `\LoadClass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}`, and remove the `\DeclareKeys[demo-cls]` and `\ProcessKeyOptions[demo-cls]`.

Comment: @Skillmon yes, my real class does have options of its own.

Comment: The issue is a missing space-stripping step, in the key processing. I'm not sure since how long this issue is part of the kernel (there was an optimisation at the `expl3`-layer roughly a month back if memory serves me right, in which one such space-removal was removed because it should've been applied later anyway, I'm not sure whether that's the issue here, or whether we have an issue at the `ltkeys` level -- I'll further investigate, expect a fix in the next release).

Comment: Meanwhile I found the issue, created a bug report (https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1238) and opened a PR, so expect this to be fixed by the next LaTeX release

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the underlying issue is caused by a small bug in the LaTeX kernel, which was meanwhile reported for development, and a fix is already proposed. It doesn't require any action on SX anymore.

Comment: For the meantime, if the warning bothers you: Simply using `\documentclass[lang=hebrew,notation=math,foo=baz]{demo-cls}` should work without the warning.

Comment: @Skillmon do we really close these as off topic? seems a bit negative for the OP, it's reporting a genuine latex bug, with a nice enough test file, this is one of the few kinds of question I upvote.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle we did so in the past already. I really appreciate the question (and upvoted it as well). We could reopen it, and leave an answer explaining the origin of the bug, and that it'll be fixed.

Comment: @Skillmon Other people may still bump into the question up to one year since the bug is fixed (TeX live release, or more if people are slow to update), and it's way more easy to find the information if it is in an answer compared to if it's buried in the comments.

Comment: @Skillmon answer posted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug handling the option lists in the new l3keys based option handler. You can avoid the spurious warning by ensuring there is no excess white space between the options, so

```
\documentclass[lang=hebrew,notation=math,foo=baz]{demo-cls}
```

in this example.

The code has already been fixed (in a pull request from @Skillmon) in the latex sources so it will be fixed in an upcoming release.

Bug report

https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1238

Pull request with fix

https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/pull/1239

Thanks for the report and clean test file.